# Query to get data from table2 based on info in table1

Tags: sql

Alright, let's say I have 2 tables.

Table 1 has:

```
ServerName         |    ServerIP 

Something1         |    192.168.0.1
Something2         |    192.168.0.2
Something3         |    192.168.0.3
```

Table 2 has:

```
PlayerName         |    PlayerIP

MyName1            |    192.168.0.1
MyName2            |    192.168.0.1
MyName3            |    192.168.0.2
```

How can I get all players(table2) that match the ServerIP in table1?

Comment: Do you mean all the players for a specific IP (192.168.0.1)? Or do you want to do something like match players with usernames?

Comment: As suggested, putting this as a comment now:

Have you tried doing this yourself yet? I would really suggest attempting it first. Read about [SQL JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) here, and let me know if you have trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t2.PlayerName 
from 
  table2 t2, table1 t1 
where
  t2.PlayerIP = t1.ServerIP
```

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudo SQL..

`SELECT table2.playername from table2 JOIN table1 ON table1.serverip = table2.ip`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join)

```
SELECT t2.PlayerName, t1.ServerIP 
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ServerIP = t2.IP
```